# C# The URI prefix is not recognized using ms-appx

Tags: c#, wpf, url, uri

I'm having a problem in my C# code. It always ends up with this error: `System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.`

The code where this error happens:

```
gameCover_img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/PlaceHolder.png"));
```

Adding `Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.png"` in WPF works fine and displays the image. But I need to change it programmatically in my C# code.

Also using an online URL instead of the local Assets folder works fine with this code.

I hope someone knows a solution for my problem.

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ms-appx scheme name is used to address the installation folder in a path. This scheme applies to Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 | Windows Phone OS 7.1.

If you are making a WPF application, then ms-appx is invalid, as WPF uses it's own URI schemes like pack: uri scheme, siteoforigin: uri scheme.

[Pack URIs in WPf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Installation folder URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that. I solved it this way: `gameCover_img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/GameLauncher;component/Assets/PlaceHolder.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`

Comment: Also consider upvoting the answer if it's the correct answer. The uri which you are using works when your image is embedded as resource in your assembly.

Comment: allright thanks! I would have upvoted if I could. Sadly not enough reputation.